# RapidMiner - range by occurence

Tags: frequency, rapidminer

I want to filter my results (document occurrence) by the most frequent (the 10 most popular them). How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `sort` operator followed by a `filter`.  For example, sorting and filtering the sample Iris dataset by `a1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.2.008">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.2.008" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true" height="417" width="675">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="5.2.008" expanded="true" height="60" name="Retrieve" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="sort" compatibility="5.2.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Sort" width="90" x="179" y="30">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="a1"/>
        <parameter key="sorting_direction" value="decreasing"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="5.2.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Filter Example Range" width="90" x="313" y="30">
        <parameter key="first_example" value="1"/>
        <parameter key="last_example" value="10"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve" from_port="output" to_op="Sort" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Sort" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Example Range" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```